# How to upload data from zip file to MySQL database using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, import, merge, phpmyadmin

I have a client who got a zipped file that has all the database they had in the SaaS app they were using. Now, we have a similar app but our column names are different (obviously) and in some cases we have less columns. So, now i want to upload all this data to my database but i am not sure how to do it?

I run phpmyadmin on the servers.

Comment: How was the data exported? i.e. What's in the zip file? CSV? SQL?

Comment: the zipped file had .sql extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extract the file on your desktop.
2. Login to your phpMyAdmin account.
3. Click the Import tab.
4. Select the file to import, file format, ect. and click Go.
5. Browse through the structure of the imported database to the columns of interest.  For each column, click the pencil icon to edit the column (i.e. rename it), or click the X icon to delete it.

To *merge* data sets, after importing the tables, you would need to run your own query in the SQL tab to merge the data sets.

Comment: thanks! but with step #5 we are setting up a new table with that data.  But we need that data from the zipped file to be inserted into the new accounts data tables.  So lets say a client used Salesforce for CRM and they have all that data, and now our company, say highrisehq and now we have to insert all that data to the new account.

Comment: After importing the database, go to the table you want to rename, and click on the Operations tab.  Then in the Table Options section you can rename the table.

Comment: but wouldn't renaming the new table to our table name replace everything from our table and make the new table the default data set?

Comment: That depends on how your application is configured and where it goes to get its "default data set."  Renaming a table just renames the table; it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: no i mean lets say the table in which the new data should go is called `contact_names` then the new data is supposed to be inserted into tha table.  So now you suggested i first import the table into the database then i rename the new table to the name of the table in which i need this inserted... So wouldn't that mess it up..? or tell you that account names don't match.

Comment: Importing a database should only be done when initializing a new database (so that you don't have to start from scratch) or restoring a crashed/corrupted database.  Once a table is given a name, and the application is running/launched, the table name should never be changed.  You are correct in that changing a table's name mid-step would cause a lot of problems.  It sounds like you want the application to create new tables in the database.  Is that correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8186/discussion-between-sam-khan-and-jim-fell)

Comment: The client started using our web app a month ago so he has all new data there.  Now he wants all the other data from previous vendor to be part of his data in our database.  So imagine business contacts from that old vendor to be inserted into our business contacts section, etc.

Comment: Ah, "I see," says the blind man.  You want to *merge* data from an old database into the new database.  I don't think myPhpAdmin can do this directly.  After importing the tables, you would need to run your own query in the SQL tab to merge the data sets.

Answer (score 2):

That are two different tasks in one question,

1. phpMyAdmin is able to import ZIP-files directly – you don't need to extract them on your local machine. Also be aware of max upload sizes and maximum script execution times, when importing huge database dumps.
2. To map an existing database to another structure involves a lot of manual work, like renaming tables and columns and copying data from on table to another.
   I would suggest, you import the old/original database to some "working copy" database and have your new database separate. That way you can use MySQL-features (INSERT INTO new_db.YX … SELECT XY_a FROM old_db.XY) to copy the data where it should go.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to take a look at the data files and see how the columns/tables differ. After you sort that out you can go about about figuring out how it insert the data. If the files are large and there are quite a few i wouldnt use phpmyadmin. I'd ssh into the box and use the command line client or set the DB up for remote access and use a local copy of the client.

If youre lucky you won't have to do any processing on the data and you just map values from the old columns to the new columns as part of you [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement. Whatever you do youll want to test all this on a dummy db(s) first before you go running it in a live environment.